# How can I use my HERE credentials to auth in Matlab (Automated Driving Toolbox)?

Tags: matlab, here-api

I am trying to use `hereHDLMCredentials setup` to access HERE HD Live Maps in Matlab.
The [Matlab help page](https://de.mathworks.com/help/driving/ug/enter-here-hd-live-map-credentials.html) asks to enter 'Access Key ID' and 'Access Key Secret',
in the dialog box the input fields are named 'App ID' and 'App Code'.

I have tried it with all the possible IDs/Keys on the HERE Project Page, but all fail to authenticate and return
'Invalid App ID and App Code combination'

On the HERE Project Page, these are the available auth methods:

- JAVASCRIPT (APP ID, API Key)
- REST API KEYS(APP ID, API Key)
- REST OAuth 2.0 JSON Web Tokens (ACCESS KEY ID, ACCESS KEY SECRET)
- HERE SDKS FOR ANDROID, IOS AND FLUTTER (APP ID, ACCESS KEY ID, ACCESS KEY SECRET)
- HERE SDK FOR IOS (PREMIUM EDITION) (Requires Bundle ID)
- HERE SDK FOR ANDROID (PREMIUM EDITION) (Requires Package name)

I did not test the last 2 methods because I don't have a Bundle ID or Package name.

Is it possible to aquire login credentials for Matlab from HERE, or do I need to wait for Matlab to update their login method?
Or is there an alternative way to auth in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the help page you've linked, it looks like you are trying to access HERE HD Live Map Data. This data is currently not available through the developer portal or a Freemium account. To get access, please contact a HERE representative through the "contact us" form on the developer portal.